# Polars concat_list into list[object] (or cast into object in general)

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have this:

```
df = polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=['hello', 'world'],
  k=[1, 2],
  ))

 j (str)  k (i64)
 hello    1
 world    2
shape: (2, 2)
```

When I do this:

```
df.select(polars.concat_list(polars.all()))
```

I get a `list[str]`:

```
 j (list[str])
 ["hello", "1"]
 ["world", "2"]
shape: (2, 1)
```

i.e. it casts `int`s into `str`s.

I'd like to get this:

```
df = polars.DataFrame(dict(
  j=[['hello', 1], ['world', 2]],
  ))

 j (object)
 ['hello', 1]
 ['world', 2]
shape: (2, 1)
```

I tried casting:

```
df.select(polars.all().cast(object))
```

but that resulted in an exception:

```
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: cannot convert object to arrow
```

Any ideas how to do both:

1. Concat all columns of each row into `list[object]`
2. Cast columns into `object` in general

?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want this? You can use a struct to keep the separate types. `df.select(pl.struct(pl.all()))`

Comment: @jqurious Downstream requirements. Structs *might* be a workaround in this particular case. I'd still be interested in seeing if there's a solution (and also how to cast to `object` in general), but please add your comment as an answer in case nobody chimes in, so I can accept it at least as a workaround.

Comment: Okay, but if have `list[object]` you can't really do much with it, e.g. you can't use any of the `.write_*` methods. How would the result be passed downstream?

Comment: @jqurious Right now it's converted with `df.to_dicts()` (which should produce `[{'j': ['hello', 1]}, {'j': ['world', 2]}]`) and then processed as "normal" python list.

Comment: Ah right. Can you just do the list creation on the python side? e.g. `[ {'j': list(row.values())} for row in df.to_struct('').to_list() ]`

Comment: @jqurious `Can you just do the list creation on the python side?`  Yeah that's another workaround, thanks! Though I'm still interested in why there's a difference in creating these two and how to cast things to object.

Comment: `Object` is basically a placeholder for "I do not understand/support this datatype" - so I don't think you can explicitly cast something to it.